# Issue uploading/accessing S3 uploads with IHP

Tags: amazon-s3, ihp

I am having an issue with S3 in IHP, or the IHP plugin for it.

I'm saving files to AWS storage, I get an url back to save in the database, but nothing gets saved in S3. And no error message from IHP.

I have double checked bucket name and region, and access keys is connected to an IAM with AmazonS3FullAccess permissions.

I get 403 forbidden when trying to access signed urls.

Any ideas where things could have gone wrong?

Currently my controller looks like this as I per the docs is instructed to save the whole link, using the `createTemporaryDownloadUrlFromPath` won't work, so there are currently some holes in the docs.

```hs
    action CreateDriverAction = do
        let driver = newRecord @Driver
        driver
            |> buildDriver
            |> validateNewDriver
            >>= uploadToStorage #licenceBackUrl
            >>= pure . validateField #licenceFrontUrl (nonEmpty |> withCustomErrorMessage "Bilde av forsiden på førerkortet er obligatorisk")
            >>= pure . validateField #licenceBackUrl (nonEmpty |> withCustomErrorMessage "Bilde av baksiden på førerkortet er obligatorisk")
            >>= ifValid \case
                Left driver -> do
                    render NewView{..}
                Right driver -> do
                    hashed <- hashPassword (get #passwordHash driver)
                    driver <- driver |> set #passwordHash hashed |> createRecord
                    login driver
                    redirectToPath "/driver/"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When accessing files that are not publicly allowed, there are some extra steps to it, and

You must access files with `fileOrNothing` and do some more manual steps.

My action ended opp looking like this:

```hs
    action CreateDriverAction = do
        let driver = newRecord @Driver
        let licenceFrontFile = fileOrNothing "licenceFrontUrl"
        let licenceBackFile = fileOrNothing "licenceBackUrl"

        driver
            |> buildDriver
            |> set #licenceBackPath (maybe "" (cs . get #fileContent) licenceBackFile)
            |> set #licenceFrontPath (maybe "" (cs . get #fileContent) licenceBackFile)
            |> validateField #licenceFrontPath (nonEmpty |> withCustomErrorMessage "Bilde av forsiden på førerkortet er obligatorisk")
            |> validateField #licenceBackPath (nonEmpty |> withCustomErrorMessage "Bilde av baksiden på førerkortet er obligatorisk")
            |> validateNewDriver
            >>= ifValid \case
                Left driver -> do
                    setErrorMessage "Noe gikk galt med fører-registrering. Sjekk at skjemafeltene er korrekte og send inn på nytt"
                    render NewView{..}
                Right driver ->
                    do
                        storedLicenceFront <-
                            storeFileWithOptions
                                (licenceFrontFile |> fromMaybe (error "No file"))
                                ( def
                                    { directory = "drivers/licenceFront"
                                    , contentDisposition = contentDispositionAttachmentAndFileName
                                    }
                                )

                        storedLicenceBack <-
                            storeFileWithOptions
                                (licenceBackFile |> fromMaybe (error "No file"))
                                ( def
                                    { directory = "drivers/licenceBack"
                                    , contentDisposition = contentDispositionAttachmentAndFileName
                                    }
                                )

                        licenceBackSigned <- createTemporaryDownloadUrlFromPath (get #path storedLicenceBack)
                        licenceFrontSigned <- createTemporaryDownloadUrlFromPath (get #path storedLicenceFront)
                        hashed <- hashPassword (get #passwordHash driver)
                        driver <-
                            driver |> set #passwordHash hashed
                                |> set #licenceFrontPath (get #path storedLicenceFront)
                                |> set #licenceBackPath (get #path storedLicenceBack)
                                |> set #licenceBackUrl (get #url licenceBackSigned)
                                |> set #licenceFrontUrl (get #url licenceFrontSigned)
                                |> set #licenceFrontUrlExpiresAt (get #expiredAt licenceFrontSigned)
                                |> set #licenceBackUrlExpiresAt (get #expiredAt licenceBackSigned)
                                |> createRecord
                        setSuccessMessage "Din førerprofil er opprettet! Vi behandler søknaden din snarest."
                        login driver
                        redirectToPath "/driver/"
```